# Bootstrap select inside modal don't show properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-select

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gj9axc18/3/). I've put a `Select` box as sample. It seems that it can't be shown inside modal. How can be it solved?

**...................................................Update.....................................**

To solve this, I've added this CSS:

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu.inner {
    position: static;
}
```

Now, the Select-Option are showing, but it seems that the dropdown taking the real space which increasing the height of popup. But, I expect **dropdown will cross the popup window if the height of dropdown is much**. How can I make it?

[image]

[image]

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gj9axc18/4/)

Answer (score 4):

See the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/gj9axc18/5/ You need to add this to your CSS:

```
.modal { overflow: visible; }
.modal-body { overflow-y: visible !important; }
```

I also took the liberty of including the plugins corresponding CSS file from a CDN:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css
```

Comment: your two line CSS code will bring this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gj9axc18/6/
Actually, I want scroll-able popup if it cross the browser window like this: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gj9axc18/7/
Inside it, I want dropdown of select cross the popup window if it's height is increasing much (like your fiddle)